# C# FileWatcher filter

Tags: c#, string, file-watcher

I have a method in my service where I'm watching the services config file. It looks like this:

```
private void WatchConfigurationFile()
{
    var fileLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;


    watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileLocation);
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Filter = fileLocation + ".config";

    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnConfigChange);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


    Log.DebugFormat("config location: {0}", watcher.Filter.ToString());

}
```

The log returns the complete file path location of my targeted file, including the location of where it is stored: C/Users etc etc

Yet, when I update my config file, the changes aren't displayed in my log files. The logging is done like this:

```
private void OnConfigChange(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    Log.DebugFormat("Updated ConnectionString: {0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"]);
}
```

However in my file watcher class, if I change the filter to the actual name of the file, which in my case is the service exe name with a '.config' at the end. It works fine.

Why is it one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: may be  (app_name).vshost.exe.config  needs to update too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `watcher.Filter =  "*.config";` for all config files or else `watcher.Filter =  "yourFileName.config";` for a specific file. No need to specify the full path here;

> As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter(v=vs.110).aspx):
>   To watch changes in all files, set the Filter property to an empty
>   string (""). To watch a specific file, set the Filter property to the
>   file name. For example, to watch for changes in the file MyDoc.txt,
>   set the Filter property to "MyDoc.txt". You can also watch for changes
>   in a certain type of file. For example, to watch for changes in any
>   text files, set the Filter property to "*.txt". Use of multiple
>   filters such as "*.txt|*.doc" is not supported.